# Unable to login in Android Webview

Tags: android, webview

I've got a webview application to display new posts and pictures and... on my website. I'd also give the user the ability to login to their schoolaccount and that is where I'm stuck. I can't seem to login to the website... Everything else works in the webview, could someone help me with this one?

Code:

```
// Opslag //
    webView.clearHistory();
    webView.clearCache(true);
    // WebView //
    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    // Performance webview + style //
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    // Laden URL //
    webView.loadUrl("http://scheppersonline.be/berichten_mobiel/");
    final MyWebClient myWebViewClient = new MyWebClient();
    webView.setWebViewClient(myWebViewClient);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
    // Hide bar when app is loading //
    findViewById(R.id.toolbar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // Downloaden bestanden //
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Kind regards
Bram

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step recipe which produces the problem. What exactly are the steps the user follows?

Comment: does the website support logging in on mobile browsers?

Comment: The user will be redirected to this page to login: asoscheppers-mechelen.schoolonline.be That's all there is to it, but it just doesn't work :/ And eys, mobile login is supported for the website!